# Issues with GRAILS UUID and PSQL

Tags: grails, grails-orm, uuid, psql

I am trying to use UUID2 generator on grails 2.4.4, PSQL version 9.4.4. My current model setup is.

```
class ClassA {

   UUID id

   static mapping = {
       id generator:'uuid2', name:'uuid2', type:'pg-uuid'
       tablePerHierarchy false
   }
}
```

and

```
class ClassB extends ClassA {

    static constraints = {
    }

    static mapping = {
    }
}
```

but when I perform a run-app i always get an error.

*ERROR context.GrailsContextLoaderListener  - Error initializing the application: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [ClassB]:  null
Message: Error evaluating ORM mappings block for domain [ClassB]:  null*

Any ideas what I did wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rename `UUID id` to `UUID uuid2` or remove `name: uuid2`. As far as I know with name in mapping you assign the id generator to one of your properties.

[enter link description here](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/ref/Database%20Mapping/id.html)